# Children div with border push down when browser zoom out

Tags: html, css

```
#container{width:100px; height:200px; border:solid 1px #000;}

#container div{float:left;}

#a, #b{width:50px; height:50px;}
#a{background:red;}
#b{background:yellow;}

#c, #d{width:48px; height:48px; border:solid 1px #000;}
#c{background:blue;}
#d{background:green;}
```

//without border

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

//with border

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="c"></div>
    <div id="d"></div>
</div>
```

I have 2 divs inside on container, both float left

However, if I add border into small divs,

When browser zoom out, div will push to bottom and destroy the layout

I have try without border and layout works fine without border.

anyone know how to achieve it with border's div?

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnk8s2qm/)

Comment: If it helps, it's broken for me in Chrome and FF but works okay in IE.

Comment: ya safari broken too, only works in IE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to set:

```
Box-sizing: Border-box;
```

it tells the border to grow inside instead of outside, that way it doesnt change the layout.

also change the box's width back to 50px.

<kbd>**[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/bnk8s2qm/1/)**</kbd>

PS: jsfiddle doesnt recognize this property, but renders it as needed.

Comment: if i  grow inside, is this mean, my small div space will be 48*48?

Comment: exactly. and the outer width will be as the width you set.